# Taking data from a windows

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms

What I need to do is basically take the users name (which is already stored as a variable) and their score (which is also a variable) and store it in my database when they press 'submit'. Here is the code I have for the button click.

```
private void btnSubmitScore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connStr = "server=server; " +
                     "database=databasename; " +
                     "uid=username; " +
                     "pwd=password;";
    MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
}
```

Obviously i have changed the `login` details etc. I have had a look around and have only managed to find confusing codes about how to display data from a database in a form (i will do this later), but for now, i need to know how to add `sName` and `iTotalScore` into the database. (Fields are called `'Name'` and `'Score'` in DB)

Comment: Please try to post cleaner code samples. This one isn't exactly unreadable but it's a good habit to get into in that it's one less thing to bug potential answerers.

Comment: Also, Connector/NET comes with tutorials: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-net-tutorials-intro.html . This seems like the kind of subject matter they should cover adequately.

Comment: i had a look at the link but it all just makes very little sense to me, i just cant get my head around it. Would it help if i posted my whole code for my form?

Comment: Posting more code rarely helps, unless it's where your actual problem lies. Seeing as your problem lies in not being able to work through a tutorial...

Comment: its not that i am unable to, but that it seems in the tutorial they are not using the forms but using the console, so i am not sure what parts can be used or manipulated to fit into the code of my form so it will work. Please excuse my poopness, i dont have alot of practice at coding and i usually do figure it out by searching on google, but i couldnt seem to find the relevant information

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the MySql connector, but the code should be something along the lines of:

```
private void Insert()
{
    string connStr = "server=server; " +
                 "database=databasename; " +
                 "uid=username; " +
                 "pwd=password;";

    string query = "INSERT INTO TableName('Name','Score) VALUES (@name, @score);";

    using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        MySqlCommand insertCommand = new MySqlCommand(connection,command);
        insertCommand.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@name",sName);
        insertCommand.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@score",iTotalScore);
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
   }
}
```

Comment: As @millimoose mentioned, you should probably consult the documentation for the exact syntax.

Comment: You've repeated your `@name` parameter instead of also adding `@score`.  (I'll edit to fix!)

Answer (score 0):

You are going to use a combination of `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and their properties. the connection is essentially the stuff of your code. The command is a literal SQL statement, or a call to a stored procedure.

A common C# idiom is to form your code around the very first line as shown here:

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection()) {
    string doThis = "select this, that from someTable where this is not null";
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(dothis, myConnection);

    try {
       myCommand.Connection.Open();
       myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(); //pretend "myReader" was declared earlier

    } catch (Exception myEx) {
         // left to your imagination, and googling.
    }
    finally {
        myCommand.Connection.Close();
    }
}

// do something with the results. Your's to google and figure out
```

The general outline is

1. Using a connection
2. instantiate and configure an SqlCommand
3. Use try/catch as shown.
4. The "using" block gives use behind the scenes cleanup/disposal of all those objects we don't need anymore when we're done; in particular the SqlConnection object.

You must learn more about these Sqlxxxxx classes, there's lots of ways to configure them to do what you want.

Comment: You have described a Sql select well, but the question is referring to an `INSERT` (or perhaps `UPDATE`) operation.